# Will mortgage rates in the future be lower?

Tags: mortgage

Currently we have mortgage rates in 6-7 percentage rage. This is relatively low when it comes to history. Yet everyone keeps telling that the rates will be lower so even if I buy a house today I can still refinance it in the coming years. Why would rates go down though or what would cause it? Are they already low from looking at the last 75y of history?

Comment: Who's everyone?

Comment: (1) Who can see the future?  (2) How low is “lower”?  (3) You still need a place to live.  Just don’t over-buy.

Comment: Do these "everyone" have vested interest in selling you a house? (Real estate agent, mortgage broker, etc.)

Comment: This question is pure speculation. Even if we *would* know where in the world you are looking for a mortgage (which you forgot to mention), we couldn't answer this question without a crystal ball.

Comment: The question solicits a prediction of the future, and so cannot be answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the numbers you provide, I assume you are based in the US. Similar explanations do hold for the Eurozone as well, although interest rates are lower.

In any case, looking at historical rates is misleading. Interest rates are set by central banks based on the [mandates](https://www.stlouisfed.org/in-plain-english/the-fed-and-the-dual-mandate#:%7E:text=The%20Federal%20Reserve%20System%20has,other%20words%2C%20conducting%20monetary%20policy.) they have to fulfill (e.g. maximum employment and price stability in the US). GDP growth (forecasts) are moderate (little pressure on inflation), and inflation is expected to decline. Both situations point towards low(er) interest rates going forward. Mortgage rates in turn are based on the central bank rate.

**EDIT**

If inflation declines to desired levels, and the economy is not expected to overheat, interest rates are usually assumed to decline. A simple analogy is using brakes on a car. If you drive 80 and want to slow down to 50 you hit the breaks. Once you reach 50, you do not stay on your brakes but release the pressure. You can think of interest rates to work in a similar way. Raising rates is like pushing the brakes. Once the economy / inflation slows down, the central bank removes the breaks because otherwise the economy would slow down even further.

I suggest asking at [economics stackexchange](https://economics.stackexchange.com/) if you desire more scientific explanations.

**Edit end**

The expectations come from a number of indicators. For instance, current inflation expectations are low ([FRED 5y5y Forward inflation expectation rate](https://fred.stlouisfed.org/series/T5YIFR)):

[image]

You can read details about this calculation [here](https://quant.stackexchange.com/a/65713/54838).

The Federal Open Market Committee (FOMC) [projections](https://www.federalreserve.gov/monetarypolicy/fomcprojtabl20221214.htm) show that the central bank board members and Federal Reserve Bank presidents project PCE inflation to decrease substantially and that the FED Funds Rate is expected to decline as well.

[image]

The FED funds rate projections can also be found on the FRED website:
[image]

Interest rate derivatives (Futures and OIS Swap rates) carry information about expected interest rates hikes. The [FED watch tool](https://www.cmegroup.com/markets/interest-rates/cme-fedwatch-tool.html) computes implied probabilities of interest rate hikes (see [here](https://money.stackexchange.com/a/155169/109107) for an explanation of the logic behind these computations).

[image]

A word of caution: the only certainty about the future is that it is uncertain!

- hardly anyone expected inflation to increase as it did (it is also a bit far stretched to assume one could forecast a war with any reasonable accuracy in the next few years); higher inflation will result in higher rates
- when crises hit is unpredictable: there will always be times of financial distress, and more often than not, one can only explain it reasonable well with the benefit of hindsight; in any case, lower growth and recessions lead to lower rates

**Considerations**

You will never buy anything at the best time for the best price. There are a few considerations:

- If you enter into a variable rate mortgage, you will have your rate automatically adjust to the current interest rate situation: if the rate declines, good for you; if it increases further, you will pay that amount
- If you enter a fixed rate loan (provided it will last for the entire mortgage term), you will be immune to any changes in interest rates (if rates were to decline, you will miss out on that; if they increase, it does not matter for you).
- Fixed rate loans will always be (slightly) more expensive at initiation compared to variable rate loans (the banks takes the interest rate risk). If you are comfortable with paying the current rate and do not want to worry about any changes, they offer you the best solution.
- The cost of Refinancing depends on the contract terms. In almost all cases, there will be fees.
- Purchasing a house will likely be the biggest single expense in your life. Get different quotes and compare the overall cost of the mortgage (not some teaser rates at the beginning etc.)

Comment: Thanks, I understand the deep dependency between fed rates and mortgage however the related question then why fed rates are supposed to be lower than? Even if the inflation goes down, does it cause rates to be lower too? Can't we have desired inflation rate with present rates for much longer?

Answer (score 4):

> Yet everyone keeps telling that the rates will be lower so even if I
> buy a house today I can still refinance it in the coming years.

Over the last 20 plus years since the rates dropped due to events in the late 1990's and early 2000's there would be waves of refinances because rates were at historic lows and this the time to buy.  When there were signs there would an increase in rates, there were even more advertisements telling you to lock in rates now. when they appeared to be going down they reminded you you could always refinance later for a low rate.

Nobody knows what the rates will be next year, or the year after that. They have no idea if we are in a housing bubble; and if we are when it will burst.

Buying what you can't afford because rates will be lower soon, is dangerous. We have seen that before. Locking in rates now because they are going to get worse can also cause problems if you aren't buying what you need.

> Why would rates go down though or what would cause it? Are they
> already low from looking at the last 75y of history?

What they were decades ago is interesting, but doesn't tell you what will happen, or what should happen, or what somebody hopes will happen.

Answer (score 0):

They could be right and rates could go down, in which case you could refinance once it drops low enough to make it worth the closing costs of a new loan.

They could be wrong and rates could go up, in which case you can sleep knowing you have a below-market mortgage.

Either way, you need to make sure you can safely afford the house you're buying based on today's rates, and not overbuy speculating that rates will go down.

Answer (score 0):

Reminder: If rates go down, you can refinance to a lower rate, sometimes "in place" with the same bank (avoiding some fees). My original 20-year mortgage was 6.5% fixed, right before the derivatives crashed the lending market; I refinanced down to 3.25% fixed near the bottom of that swing.

There are lots of calculators on the web that can help you determine whether refinancing makes sense, balancing the paperwork costs against the possible interest savings.

Basically, if you are ready to buy, the current rate affects whether you can afford the payments now, and you can deal with the future in the future.

Don't forget other costs of homeownership. Insurance, especially flood insurance if the property requires it, is an ongoing cost along with your loan payments. (Often bundled into the payment, in the US.) Maintenance. Repairs. Utilities. Taxes (also often bundled into the monthly loan payment). Homeowners association dues, if you're stuck with that.

And I set aside 10% of the purchase price for renovations I wanted to make shortly after buying (replacing the heating system and taking out some walls).

But congrats on being in a position where you're considering buying, and good luck with it! Just remember, every house comes with a free set of hobbies...